# passing a parameter to the Breeze WebAPI Controller class (NOT the controller action/method) from the client-side javascript

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I have a Web API controller (which happens to be a Breeze controller in my case) and this controller is using the Entity Framework for database access. At design time it is tied to a particular database (DB1) via the connection string (Conn1) present in the Web.config file. I have two other databases DB2 and DB3 with exactly the same schema as DB1 but with different data. I want the ability to switch to a different database DB2 or DB3 at runtime when the user in browser/client SPA chooses to do so. Thus I want to pass his choice as a string to the Web API Controller class (maybe it's constructor - don't know) so as to then pass it to the DbContext class' constructor. But obviously this has to be before any actions of the controller are invoked. I am at loss as to what can be done.

Partial code is as below:

```
[BreezeController]
public class QuickStaffController : ApiController
{
    //public readonly EFContextProvider<QuickStaffDbContext> _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<QuickStaffDbContext>();

public readonly EFContextProvider<QuickStaffDbContext> _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<QuickStaffDbContext>(string connectionStringFromClient);

    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Metadata();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public SaveResult SaveChanges(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject saveBundle)
    {
        return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
    }
... Action methods


public partial class QuickStaffDbContext : DbContext
{
    public QuickStaffDbContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

WebAPI `ApiController` objects inherit an [Initialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.initialize(v=vs.118).aspx) method, which takes an [HttpControllerContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.controllers.httpcontrollercontext(v=vs.118).aspx).  From the HttpControllerContext, you can get the Request.  If you can determine/lookup your connection string from some information in the Request, you can create your DbContext from that.

```
public EFContextProvider<QuickStaffDbContext> _contextProvider; 

protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
{
    var request = controllerContext.Request;
    var path = request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath;
    string connectionString;
    if (path.StartsWith("/breeze/db2/") {
        connectionString = Db2ConnectionString; // perform a lookup somehow
    } else {
        connectionString = Db1ConnectionString;
    }

    _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<QuickStaffDbContext>(string connectionString);
}
```

You can use the technique in Steve Greene's answer to build the connection string, once you know what string to build.

Comment: @Steven Schmitt Thanks. But I am still not clear what is the best place to pass the DB identifier string from the client side javascript call to the Controller that I can read in the Initialize override. I don't think I can pass it in the Request Uri since the this is a single controller with a unique Uri. So is the request header an option or is there a better place?

Comment: Yes, a request header would make sense.  See [Configuring an AJAX adapter](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/controlling-ajax) for more info.  A second option (outside of Breeze) would be using a cookie.  That has the advantage of automatically being "sticky".

Answer (score 0):

If it is SQL, try the SQLConnectionStringBuilder with some variation along these lines:

```
public partial class QuickStaffDbContext : DbContext
{
    public QuickStaffDbContext()
        : base(MyConnectionString())
    {
    }
}

private static string MyConnectionString()
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    string datasource = {... aply your logic }
    sqlBuilder.DataSource = datasource;
    sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = "YYY";
    sqlBuilder.PersistSecurityInfo = true;
    sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
    sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;

    return sqlBuilder.ToString();
}
```